# How can I avoid missing images when using ggplot_image in gt table with fmt_markdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gt

I am using the gt functions ggplot_image and fmt_markdown to embed ggplot images in each row of a dataframe.

I have created a simple function which returns a ggplot object. I use this to add a ggplot image to each row of a small dataframe and then display the dataframe as a gt table. The first version of the table is displayed as expected with an image in each row:

[gt table with ggplot images displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXVlc.png)

If I change the aspect ratio of the images then one of the images is not displayed correctly:

[gt table where one ggplot image is not displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIhax.png)

Here is the first version of my code, which gives the expected result as seen in the first image above.

The code does the following:

- Define the function which returns a ggplot object
- Create a dataframe with 5 rows of data:
- Use the barplot function to add a ggplot image to each row and convert using ggplot_image
- convert the dataframe to a gt table using the fmt_markdown function to display the ggplot images

```
library(dplyr)    # version 1.1.2 
library(ggplot2)  # version 3.5.0
library(gt)       # version 0.10.1

# function used to create individual plots in ggplot
# arguments: f1-f5 five values used to define height of columns

barplot <- function(f1=NA, f2=NA, f3=NA, f4=NA, f5=NA){
  
  C_names <- c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5")
  
  df_plot <- data.frame(
    C = C_names,
    f = c(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5)
  ) %>% 
    mutate(f = ifelse(is.na(f), 0, f))
  
  p <- ggplot(df_plot, aes(x=C, y=f, fill=C)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position="none") 
  
  return(p)
}

# data frame with f values for 5 items A, B, C, D, E
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  f1 = c(0.183, 0.102, 0.102, 0.219, 0.14),
  f2 = c(0.297, 0.287, 0.287, 0.34, 0.174),
  f3 = c(0.498, 0.583, 0.452, 0.377, 0.239),
  f4 = c(0.022, 0.028, 0.155, 0.058, 0.262),
  f5 = c(0, 0, 0.004, 0.006, 0.185)
)

# gt table with barplots created using barplot function  
df1 <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    gg = barplot(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5) %>%
      ggplot_image(height = px(20), aspect_ratio=2)) 

# convert to gt table, using fmt_markdown to display the images

df1 %>% 
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns=c(gg))
```

If I create a second version of the table using a different aspect ratio, the image in the 4th row is not displayed correctly:

```
# second version of gt table using a different aspect ratio in ggplot_image function
df2 <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    gg = barplot(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5) %>%
      ggplot_image(height = px(20), aspect_ratio=2.5)) 

df2 %>% 
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns=c(gg))
```

This example should show that changing one parameter related to the images (aspect ratio) can affect whether or not all of the images are displayed correctly.

I have not tested extensively and do not (yet) have reproducible examples for all of these parameters but it appears that different combinations of the following parameters can cause issues with images not displaying correctly. And it is not always the same images which are affected.

Parameters which I have found to be relevant include:

**width** argument in geom_bar()

**aspect_ratio** argument in ggplot_image()

**height** argument in ggplot_image()

So, my question is really this:

*Can I predict (and thereby avoid) which combinations of parameters will cause issues with displaying images?*

Or is there something else I have missed completely?

**Edited to include the contents of gg**

**Edited (#2) to include the contents of the html export from RStudio at the end (excluding the string in the img tag). Due to limited space, this contains only the table row with missing image**

**df1$gg[4]:**
"<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="height:20px;">"

**df2$gg[4]:**
"<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="height:20px;">"

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>body{background-color:white;}</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="ijxrmgaxmt" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:auto;width:auto;height:auto;">
  <style>#ijxrmgaxmt table {
font-family: system-ui, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt thead, #ijxrmgaxmt tbody, #ijxrmgaxmt tfoot, #ijxrmgaxmt tr, #ijxrmgaxmt td, #ijxrmgaxmt th {
border-style: none;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_table {
display: table;
border-collapse: collapse;
line-height: normal;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
color: #333333;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: auto;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-top-color: #A8A8A8;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #A8A8A8;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_caption {
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_title {
color: #333333;
font-size: 125%;
font-weight: initial;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
border-bottom-width: 0;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_subtitle {
color: #333333;
font-size: 85%;
font-weight: initial;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
border-top-width: 0;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_heading {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_bottom_border {
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_col_headings {
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_col_heading {
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: inherit;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
vertical-align: bottom;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_column_spanner_outer {
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: inherit;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-right: 4px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_column_spanner_outer:first-child {
padding-left: 0;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_column_spanner_outer:last-child {
padding-right: 0;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_column_spanner {
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
vertical-align: bottom;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
overflow-x: hidden;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_spanner_row {
border-bottom-style: hidden;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_group_heading {
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: initial;
text-transform: inherit;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: left;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_empty_group_heading {
padding: 0.5px;
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: initial;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_from_md > :first-child {
margin-top: 0;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_from_md > :last-child {
margin-bottom: 0;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_row {
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
margin: 10px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
vertical-align: middle;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_stub {
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: initial;
text-transform: inherit;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_stub_row_group {
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: initial;
text-transform: inherit;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
vertical-align: top;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_row_group_first td {
border-top-width: 2px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_row_group_first th {
border-top-width: 2px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_summary_row {
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-transform: inherit;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_first_summary_row {
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_first_summary_row.thick {
border-top-width: 2px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_last_summary_row {
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_grand_summary_row {
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-transform: inherit;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_first_grand_summary_row {
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
border-top-style: double;
border-top-width: 6px;
border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_last_grand_summary_row_top {
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
border-bottom-style: double;
border-bottom-width: 6px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_striped {
background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05);
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_table_body {
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_footnotes {
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_footnote {
margin: 0px;
font-size: 90%;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_sourcenotes {
color: #333333;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_sourcenote {
font-size: 90%;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_left {
text-align: left;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_center {
text-align: center;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_right {
text-align: right;
font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_font_normal {
font-weight: normal;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_font_bold {
font-weight: bold;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_font_italic {
font-style: italic;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_super {
font-size: 65%;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_footnote_marks {
font-size: 75%;
vertical-align: 0.4em;
position: initial;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_asterisk {
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: 0;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_indent_1 {
text-indent: 5px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_indent_2 {
text-indent: 10px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_indent_3 {
text-indent: 15px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_indent_4 {
text-indent: 20px;
}
#ijxrmgaxmt .gt_indent_5 {
text-indent: 25px;
}
</style>
  <table class="gt_table" data-quarto-disable-processing="false" data-quarto-bootstrap="false">
  <thead>
    <tr class="gt_col_headings">
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_left" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="Name">Name</th>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_right" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="f1">f1</th>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_right" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="f2">f2</th>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_right" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="f3">f3</th>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_right" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="f4">f4</th>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_right" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="f5">f5</th>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_left" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="gg">gg</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="gt_table_body">
    <tr><td headers="Name" class="gt_row gt_left">D</td>
<td headers="f1" class="gt_row gt_right">0.219</td>
<td headers="f2" class="gt_row gt_right">0.34</td>
<td headers="f3" class="gt_row gt_right">0.377</td>
<td headers="f4" class="gt_row gt_right">0.058</td>
<td headers="f5" class="gt_row gt_right">0.006</td>
<td headers="gg" class="gt_row gt_left"><div class="gt_from_md"><img src="" style="height:20px;">
</div></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  
  
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I **cannot** reproduce this behaviour. For me both tables render fine. I have a newer version odf`dplyr` but older versions of `gt` and `ggplot2`. But since `ggplot_image`  encodes the picture as base 64 encoded data string I would be surprised if this indeed an issue of any of the packages. Could you add the content of `gg` in both cases?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm having trouble adding the contents of gg but will get back as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks for adding the `<img>` strings. They look good to me and if I paste them into a static `<html>` document they both look fine: https://codepen.io/thothal/pen/gOymrbm. Did you try to relaod your browser and force a refresh (`[Ctrl] + [F5]` in Chrome)

Comment: Thanks. In a similar test, I have pasted the <img> strings into a local html file consisting only of the following lines (shown here without the img strings):
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Version 1</h1>
<img>
<h1>Version 2</h1>
<img>
</body>
This renders all images without any problems. If I export the table to html from the viewer tab in RStudio then the problem with a missing image is still there. I have recreated the problem in Chrome, Edge and Firefox. So this must be something to do with the styling of the html by (my version of) gt?

Comment: I just edited my question to include html exported from RStudio. I have run out of characters so this is a version created by including slice(4) on df2 to select only the problematic row. And, the string content of the <img> tag is excluded.

Comment: Nope, I updated my code pen with your html and it renders just fine. Anyways, if the `<img>` works wihtout a table it must also work within a table, because if the data encoded image results in a proper format it should be rendered in any case.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm not quite sure how I did it, but in copying the problematic img string to the question text, I somehow managed to fix the problem. I have recreated it again here: https://codepen.io/ciaran_dk/pen/QWPpGym It seems that the string in the direct output contains a &frac78; character ⅞ which after I copied it to the question here became "7/8" and rendered correctly.

Comment: I have also been testing older versions of the gt package, starting with v.0.6. The problem occurs after I update from v.0.8 to v.0.9